# Silverlight 4 desktop application sometimes zooms when touching it... and cannot zoom out

Tags: silverlight, user-interface, touch

I have a Silverlight 4 desktop application which I control using a touchscreen
(on an HP Touchsmart).

Most of the time it works fine but sometimes when clicking something everything
just zooms in and every time it happens things get bigger and bigger.

The only way to get the normal size again is by restarting the application.

Has anybody got any idea what might be causing it ? Does not seem to happen in browser mode.

Is there a way to prevent zooming?

Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not experience the problem after disabling auto zoom: Application.Current.Hosts.Settings.EnableAutoZoom = false

Answer (score 1):

We experienced the same. You can try to zoom in and out by using the pinch gesture, but that does not answer your question of why it is happening in the first place.

Hoping someone would be able to shed more light on this problem.

Sanin

Comment: I did not experience the problem after disabling auto zoom:
Application.Current.Hosts.Settings.EnableAutoZoom = false;